# Safari select background image covered by arrow

Tags: html, css, forms, safari, cross-browser

I have a background image I place on my form elements when they're 'dirty' (have unsaved changes).  The image uses `background-position: right center`.

However, in Safari, the image displays underneath the black triangle, and when I mouse over it, the background image (which is small) is covered entirely by the button that appears.

I'm not sure why Safari treats the space inside the button-on-the-right-with-the-triangle as part of the space inside the right border when other browsers start the right-hand side at the left edge of that button.  meh.

Is there a CSS way to get the background image to display to the left of the dropdown arrow/button's space?  I noticed in my googlings that Safari select elements aren't on speaking terms with padding, so that's out.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jinglesthula/uwKpS/

I'm seeing the issue in Safari 5.1.7 Win7 (I don't have access to OSX to test whether it's an issue there).

Comment: Why the downvote?  It's a legit question and I've spent some time on it and put what I found so far.

Comment: You need to post code with your question. Hopefully you can isolate your issue and create a test-case on jsFiddle or jsBin.

Comment: @jinglesthula The downvote was probably by the same "purist" that downvoted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser/9851380#comment25950948_9851380

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I had the same issue now and I fixed it by resetting the appearances on safari, and other web browsers within the css, here was my solution, hope this helps.

```
select { 
    /* and then whatever styles you want*/
    background: url(http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2166/2098205368_3e3f6090ac_t.jpg) no-repeat right #fff;
    /* reset the appearances*/
    -moz-appearance: none; 
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    appearance: none;
    /* and then whatever styles you want*/

    width: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```